# Mulesoft - SFTP Connection reset

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, anypoint-studio

Trying to connect to an Azure SFTP results in a "connection reset" - same when using the "list" operation in a mule application as well as simply using the "test connection" button in the connector.

Credentials are fine and server is perfectly accessible with different FTP Clients.

Maybe you have an idea or can make more then I from the DEBUG log:

```
DEBUG org.mule.extension.sftp.internal.connection.SftpConnectionProvider: Connecting to host: 'xyz.blob.core.windows.net' at port: '22'
DEBUG com.jcraft.jsch: Connecting to xyz.blob.core.windows.net port 22
DEBUG com.jcraft.jsch: Connection established
DEBUG com.jcraft.jsch: Remote version string: SSH-2.0-AzureSSH_1.0.0
DEBUG com.jcraft.jsch: Local version string: SSH-2.0-JSCH-0.1.54
DEBUG com.jcraft.jsch: CheckCiphers: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,arcfour,arcfour128,arcfour256
DEBUG com.jcraft.jsch: CheckKexes: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521
DEBUG com.jcraft.jsch: CheckSignatures: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
DEBUG com.jcraft.jsch: SSH_MSG_KEXINIT sent
DEBUG com.jcraft.jsch: Disconnecting from xyz.blob.core.windows.net port 22
ERROR org.mule.extension.sftp.internal.connection.SftpConnectionProvider: Session.connect: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Session.connect: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

Comment: `Credentials are fine and server is perfectly accessible with different FTP Clients` Did you mean SFTP clients?

Comment: I meant establishing a SFTP connection, using Filezilla, Transmit or similiar works fine...

Answer (score 0):

The issue can happen if the preferred authentication method is missing in the SFTP configuration with the identity file specified, and the target SFTP server is only enabled for SSH key based authentication

<sftp:connection host="${sftp.host}" port="${sftp.port}" username="${sftp.username}" passphrase="${sftp.passphrase}" preferredAuthenticationMethods="#[['PUBLIC_KEY']]" identityFile="${sftp.identityfile}" connectionTimeout="${sftp.connectionTimeout}" responseTimeout="${ftp.responseTimeout}">



</sftp:connection>

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Just to understand this correctly, so far I don't use any identity file but only username / password. So I guess this shoud not be the issue? But I'll check the server settings and give an update...

Answer (score 0):

There is a known issue with connection to Azure SFTP using JSCH. See [this post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/713024/connection-to-azure-sftp-doesnt-work-using-jsch.html).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31879367)